# jQuery syntax for multiple delegated events

Tags: jquery

The jQuery docs at http://api.jquery.com/on/ mention the benefits of delegated-events using the following syntax (which attaches an event handler to only one element):

```
$('#mytable').on('click', 'tr.hoverable', function(){
    // blah
});
```

But I can't find any reference to proper syntax for attaching multiple events at once WITH delegated-events. Is there a shortcut for the following, but with tr.hoverable as a delegated event?

```
$('#mytable tr.hoverable').on({
    mouseenter: function(){
        // blah
    },
    mouseleave: function(){
        // blah
    },
    click: function(){
        // blah
    }
});
```

Or is this the only solution ...

```
$('#mytable').on('click', 'tr.hoverable', function(){
    // blah
}).on('mouseenter', 'tr.hoverable', function(){
    // blah
}).on('mouseleave', 'tr.hoverable', function(){
    // blah
});
```

?

Comment: Look at the API again... the 2nd version of the method is the one you want.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
$('#mytable').on({
    mouseenter: function(){
        // blah
    },
    mouseleave: function(){
        // blah
    },
    click: function(){
        // blah
    }
}, '.hoverable');
```

[As per this signature](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

> .on( events-map [, selector] [, data] )

Also, prefer single tagName/className/id selectors for delegation as they get optimized

Comment: Yep, that's what I was looking for :)
Could you clarify your `prefer single tagName/...` comment? I don't understand :)

Comment: @neokio I am wrong in this case as `quickParse` still gives results for `"tr.hoverable"` though not for `".class1.class2"`. It's just a side tip. To explain how event delegation works is too much for one comment :P

Comment: This is an older question/answer, but since it helped me, i thought i'd offer some clarification of the last part of the answer: simpler delegated selectors (`.hoverable`) usually perform better than compound selectors (technically, `td.hoverable`). In the OP's case, the difference is minimal & probably necessary for specificity. Just be wary of complex (and/or non-CSS) stuff like `div+table:has(td.hoverable)`... as it requires jQuery to seek multiple times for matching elements.